# Sails.js: how to use i18n function in assets/js/files.js

Tags: node.js, internationalization, sails.js

I need use i18n() in my code inside of assets/js of my sailsjs project. How can i to do it?

In my views is ok but in my js not, why?

thanks you very much.

I have sailsjs@0.10.5

Comment: In the js, you can use `__()` to translate things

Comment: @TravisWebb, not run. In my views yes, but in my /assets/js/files.js not.

Comment: @Wigiri No, sorry. :( The next week i will try again this subject. I hope to find it.

Comment: @Lamujeresponja I thought, to avoid at all costs using any text in Angular and responding with res.ok(req.__('textstring') and just displaying the response with angular, in that way angular handles less i18n. Although it is not the most optional solution in the long run.

Comment: But @Wigiri, i'm not using angular.

Comment: @Lamujeresponja either way it resides in assets/js therefore anything there will have the same issue. I am basically sending the response with data res.ok(sails.__('hola')); ...and then let my .js in assets just forward the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Wesley, but if you don't want all of the translations client side. I would suggest writing an Ajax call and make use of the following:

```
sails.__({
  phrase: 'Good day',
  locale: 'de'
});
```

This should then be returned as the German version of 'Good day'. Or you can just send the key phrase and return all your language translations of that.

Comment: If you use an Angular Controller in assets/js/ExampleCtrl.js you cannot call __() or sails.__() as it resides on server-side (nodejs). The question is how to use it in the Client Side

Comment: @Wigiri That's why I agree with Wesley. This is also why I suggested an Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

What I do, is download the translations from the server and use them client side. I never hardcode translations in my assets and I wouldn't if I were you either.

Add a route to fetch your translations (static json) and parse the JSON client side. [There are plenty of libraries that can help you from there](http://microjs.com/#i18n).

Keep in mind that it's always possible to include translations in a build for something like require.js.